# When do you say אֶת, and when do you say אֵת?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

How can one determine when the word "את" is pronounced with a t'zayray and when it is pronounced with a se'gol?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is whether it has a trop mark on it. If it has a trop then it is pronounced with a tzayray and if it doesn’t have a trop it is a segol.

Comment: If it has a tzzyray it's pronounced with a tzayray; if it has a segol it's pronounced with a segol.

Comment: @Alex I can’t argue with that. but I am explaining when it would have a tzayray or a segol

Comment: Is the trop the cause of the tzayray/segol, the effect of the tzayray/segol, or are they just correlated effects of something else? If it is just meant as a heuristic, is it common to find verses printed with trop but without nekudot?

Answer (score 1):

With four exceptions, it is always אֵת (with a tsere) when accented/stand-alone, and it is always אֶת (with a segol) when unaccented/followed by a maqef. This is an example of the general phenomenon of unaccented syllables showing vowel reduction.

The exceptions (indicated by the masorah) with an unexpected segol are [Psalms 47:5](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/27/47/5), [60:2](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/27/60/2), and [Proverbs 3:12](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/28/3/12). I'd guess that these have an implied maqef, but who knows for certain. There is one exception with an unexpected tsere: [Job 41:26](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/29/41/26); Geoffrey Khan points out (on [p513](https://www.openbookpublishers.com/product/951)) that when a word like את is followed by a maqef but is at least one syllable away from the main accent (like in our case), it will remain unreduced (other examples are Ruth 3:17, Sam 1:14:4, ...).

Comment: Worth noting that the Masorah Gedolah lists [three different accentuations for Prov 3:12](https://manuscripts.sefaria.org/leningrad-color/BIB_LENCDX_F410B.jpg); however, all have segol.